# HTML/CSS social button with sprite on hover

Tags: html, css, sprite

Hello I am trying to create HTML/CSS button with next idea:

To run sprite animation on hover with a p-text over it.

Problem:

1. Animation appears on hover, but doesn't work.
2. P-text is hided, but doesn't appears on hover.

**Fiddle:** [jsfiddle.net/6xgt5ko1/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/6xgt5ko1/6/)

**HTML:**

```
<div> 
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><p class="follow">Follow</p></a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div a {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    background: url('http://s29.postimg.org/4yqcgdcbn/128.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

div a:hover {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    background: url('http://s10.postimg.org/alazhqpu1/sprite.png');
    background-position: 0px 0px;  
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation: play 5s steps(10) infinite;
    transorm: translateZ(0);
}

@keyframes play {
    from { background-position:0px 0px; }
    to { background-position: 1280px 0px; }
 }

.follow {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    display: none;
}

.follow:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: What is the animation supposed to look like? and what browser are you using?

Comment: In addition to your jsFiddle, please add the HTML/CSS to your question. Also, there is a link button to make any link clickable so we don't have to cut and paste the link into a browser.

Comment: Animation is supposed to work like that: http://jsfiddle.net/Hyg3C/4421/ (works in chrome, didn't figure out yet with safari issues).

Comment: It doesn't work in Safari because you need `-webkit` prefixes and also the animation is paused because of `animation-play-state: paused;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You need `-wekbit` prefixes for the animations to work in Safari. Also you set `animation-play-state: paused;` so the animation doesn't run. Not sure why that doesn't affect Chrome.

```
div a:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused; // get rid of this
  animation: play 5s steps(10) infinite;
  -webkit-animation: play 5s steps(10) infinite;
  transorm: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transorm: translateZ(0);
}
@-webkit-keyframes play {
  from { background-position:0px 0px; }
  to { background-position: 1280px 0px; }
}
```

2) Like @hopkins-matt said, to see the `<p>` on hover change the css to

```
div a:hover .follow {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I've tried to follow your tips and created new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6xgt5ko1/8/, but it still doesn't start the animation, maybe you can have a look and notice something more?

Comment: sorry you also need webkit for the keyframes. check my update

Comment: Yeaaah, now everything works great. Thanks a lot, god bless you! :)

Answer (score 1):

To fix the `<p>` text issue.

Change this CSS Rule:

```
.follow:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

to this:

```
div a:hover .follow {
    display: block;
}
```